# php , apache server error, cant trace

Tags: php, apache

> OK  The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and
>   was unable to complete your request.     Please contact the server
>   administrator, admin@example.com and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might  have done that may have caused the
>   error. More information about this error may be available in the
>   server error log.

I get this message everytime I run the code. I have no idea where the error is.. I checked through the apache error file, and some other error log files..and found nothing about the mistake..how do I trace the errror

I think that is the error that I see:

```
> [8/27/2012 12:28:57 PM] Error: PHP process 35344 from the "application/x-httpd-php" pool has exited with status 255.
[8/27/2012 12:28:57 PM] Error: Read data error - unable to get read result. Code 109.
[8/27/2012 12:28:57 PM] Error: Request for C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/backlinks/cron/links-buy.php: Unable to get the response from PHP process
```

Thats what I see in the event viewer:

```
>     php-cgi.exe 
>    5.3.9.0     4ef33bca     ZendOptimizerPlus.dll 
>    0.0.549.0     4f00c7dd     c0000005     000061a1     8554     01cd8436d2089924     C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php-cgi.exe     C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\lib\optimizerplus\php-5.3.x\ZendOptimizerPlus.dll
> 112872b4-f02a-11e1-aed2-8c89a53c9045
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `die();` in the middle of your code. Try it. If error still occurs your error in first part. Then divide your error part ino two by `die();` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Open your php file. It seems to be the file /Zend/Apache2/htdocs/backlinks/cron/links-buy.php. Determine a location on your file system where to write your PHP error output. E.g. use '/home/myuser/public_html/phpDebugErrorLog.txt'. Replace this path!

Add many statements like this to your PHP file (consider the syntax of PHP). Add different numbers 1, 2, 3, ....., 100 .

```
error_log('Position 1: ' . chr(13), 3, '/home/myuser/public_html/phpDebugErrorLog.txt');
some PHP code here;
error_log('Position 2: ' . chr(13), 3, '/home/myuser/public_html/phpDebugErrorLog.txt');
some more PHP code;
error_log('Position 3: ' . chr(13), 3, '/home/myuser/public_html/phpDebugErrorLog.txt');
```

So you determine the position in your PHP file where the error happens which crashes your CGI PHP script. The last line which is shown in your error log file will give you the position in the file which has the bug. Then fix the bug in PHP.